# Python regex returns a part of the match when used with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have been trying to teach myself Python and am currently on regular expressions. The instructional text I have been using seems to be aimed at teaching Perl or some other language that is not Python, so I have had to adapt the expressions a bit to fit Python. I'm not very experienced, however, and I've hit a snag trying to get an expression to work.

The problem involves searching a text for instances of prices, expressed either without decimals, $500, or with decimals, $500.10.

This is what the text recommends:

```
\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?
```

Replicating the text, I use this code:

```
import re

inputstring = "$500.01"

result = re.findall( r'\$[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?', inputstring)

if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print("No match.")
```

However, the result is not $500.01, but rather:

```
.01
```

I find this strange. If I remove the parentheses and the optional decimal portion, it works fine. So, using this:

```
\$[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]
```

I get:

```
$500.01
```

How can I get the regular expression to return values with and without decimal portions?

Thanks.

Comment: Now **this** is a good question on regular expressions.

Comment: Jordan H. welcome to SO. It is really nice to see a user on his first day to post a question which shows research effort, is well formulated and fulfills the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
result = re.findall( r'\$[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9][0-9])?', inputstring)
                                ^^
```

The [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function returns the list of captured texts if there are any defined in the pattern, and you have one in yours. You need to get rid of it by turning it into a non-capturing one.

> **re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>   
> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

**Update**

You can shorten your regex a bit by using a *limiting quantifier* `{2}` that requires exactly 2 occurrences of the preceding subpattern:

```
r'\$[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?'
                    ^^^
```

Or even replace `[0-9]` with `\d`:

```
r'\$\d+(?:\.\d{2})?'
```

Comment: I'd also replace `[0-9][0-9]`, which looks redundant, to `[0-9]{2}` since there should be always two decimals in the price, if any.

Comment: I was thinking on the same regarding your last edit. Unfortunately I can't upvote more than once.

Comment: Your suggestion worked.Also, I'm new to stackoverflow and I realize the text in the comment box says avoid using this box to say thanks, but I don't know how else to express my gratitude on this site so I'm going to say it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: @JordanH: Glad to help. Gratitude on SO means upvoting answers that are helpful to you and accepting the answers that solve your question. Best of luck.

Comment: Even though I can't think of real life case, but what should happen if there is a string like "abc$500.01dolar". This regular expression will still find "$500.01". If you explicitly want to find only prices that begin with "$" after space and also have space after the second decimal, than the regex should also match the begin of string `^` and the end of string `$`. I don't want to split hairs, but just point out some pitfalls to the OP.

Comment: If it is validation and the whole string should only contain the price in USD, `^\$\d+(?:\d{2})?$` would work. I think here OP needs to get all occurrences from a larger string.