# Python regex findall() returning incorrect substrings

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to obtain a list of all substrings of the form:

colon + sequence of 2 letters among specified sequences + numerical value with minimum 1 digit

```
import re
DATA_SUB = ':(TI|LO|TE|HU|AN|FO)[0-9\.]+'
print(re.findall(DATA_SUB, '%145:TI15:LO1.6213:TE97$'))
```

Result:

```
['TI', 'LO', 'TE']
```

wherein it should be:

```
[':TI15', ':LO1.6213', ':TE97']
```

Looking at the re.findall() documentation:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings

one can conclude that the method above should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `DATA_SUB = ':(?:TI|LO|TE|HU|AN|FO)[0-9\.]+'`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32105510/3832970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using brackets **you defined a capture group**, and so you ask Python to return the list of captures. By placing `?:` in front of the group, you make it a **non-capture group**:

```
import re
DATA_SUB = ':(?:TI|LO|TE|HU|AN|FO)[0-9\.]+'
print(re.findall(DATA_SUB, '%145:TI15:LO1.6213:TE97$'))
```

If you for instance would define *two* capture groups, you will generate a list of tuples with the captures of the two groups:

```
# educational counter example

import re
DATA_SUB = ':(TI|LO|TE|HU|AN|FO)([0-9\.]+)'
print(re.findall(DATA_SUB, '%145:TI15:LO1.6213:TE97$'))
```

will generate:

```
[('TI', '15'), ('LO', '1.6213'), ('TE', '97')]
```

Comment: Some unexplained downvoting

Comment: @anubhava: If I recall correctly there was some (weird) badge/hat that you could win by downvoting a lot...

Comment: The educational counter-example turned out to be what I ultimately wanted!

Comment: @wit221: note that the leading colon `:` is not matched since it is not part of any capture group. The idea of the example was of course only to show that if you use *multiple capture groups*, it will give you multiple answers per capture :).

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capture group instead of a capturing group in your regex to avoid getting captured data in the output of `findall`:

```
>>> DATA_SUB = ':(?:TI|LO|TE|HU|AN|FO)[0-9.]+'
>>> print re.findall(DATA_SUB, '%145:TI15:LO1.6213:TE97$')
[':TI15', ':LO1.6213', ':TE97']
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: I am also wondering

Comment: Thank you. Could you also explain why it is possible to remove the escape character preceding the dot, while obtaining the same desired result?

Comment: Because inside character class i.e. `[...]` all regex meta characters e.g. `., *, +` etc are treated literally.